# Python: How do I give an bunch of audio files BPM information?

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to figure out what the best Python tools would be to add BPM information to a file. The yaafe and LibXtract libraries seem to have Python bindings, but seem to be sparsely documented. How can I go about doing this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to upload your data to an external server, try using the EchoNest API -- it has good Python bindings and lots of tools for music information retrieval tasks such as this.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found [this](https://github.com/alouis93/metaBPM.py). Usage is found in the README.

```
python metaBPM.py -s [path to your music collection]
```

Comment: the metaBPM file is a wrapper around the EchoNest API, so you'll still need to be comfortable sharing data with EchoNest (I am.  but it's not a local solution).